# How to distinguish an object from an array in JSON?

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3.6 and I have a json type column. Is there any way to find out whether we are dealing with an array or an object? I mean:

```
SELECT '["x", "y"]'::json
SELECT '{"0": "x", "1": "y"}'::json
```

Or maybe it's possible to translate one notation to another? The thing is that I have to extract values which are nested inside an array or an object.

I can call "json_each" on an object, but it fails on an array:

```
SELECT * FROM json_each('{"0": "x", "1": "y"}'::json)
```

Unfortunately I can't upgrade to 9.4... which means I can't use jsonb type or new operators to test it... I appreciate your help.